# Multi_select_flutter chipdisplay is too big

Tags: flutter, dart, multi-select

This is the picture. The chips is too big
[image]
This is my code below. i want to customize the size of my chips:

```dart
 MultiSelectDialogField(
             
                
                chipDisplay: MultiSelectChipDisplay(
                  items: _items,
                  chipColor: Colors.blue,
                  textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(
                        0.2), // Set the background color of the chips
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                        10), // Set the border radius of the chips
                    border: Border.all(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        width:
                            2), // Set the border color and width of the chips
                  ),
                  onTap: (item) {
                    // Handle chip tap event
                  },
                ),
),
```

Comment: try to wrap with SizedBox

Comment: where is the picture?

Comment: Please add image of expected result and what you have achieved.

Comment: Helloo. I added the picture already

Comment: @MDYeasinSheikh I tried to wrap it still too big

Comment: I hope you are referring to the `_items`, it would nice if you include sample full snippet that will reproduce the issue